# How to call method from style binding using Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I wrote the following code:

```
<template v-slot="scope">
    <div :class="getFuncationBarClass(scope)" :style="'{ --progress: `${getFunctionPercentage(scope)}` }'">{{getFuncationTotals(scope)}}</div>
</template>
```

For some reason `getFuncationBarClass` and `getFuncationTotals` are called but `getFunctionPercentage` is not being called. I tried some other variations of `:style` but they all didn't work. How can I call the method from style binding?

Comment: You're using it as a string so it's not being called

Comment: I think it should be `:style="{ '--progress': getFunctionPercentage(scope) }"` though I'm not sure in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vue you can directly pass style objects. You can try:

```html
<div :class="getFuncationBarClass(scope)" :style="{ '--progress': getFunctionPercentage(scope) }">{{getFuncationTotals(scope)}}</div>
```